# How do i add detail when sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

Im trying to sculpt a monster in blender and i do not know how to add detail to it. It looks very blocky when using clay brushes etc. Do i need to subdivide my object for more triangles? thanks.

[image: what i've done so far]

Comment: also how do i make parts more sharp for example if i were to do scales on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dyntopo** (adaptive sculpting) is the option to use to add detail without being constrained by the underlying mesh topology. As I can see from your screenshot, you are already using it.

Be aware of the Dyntopo option: "Relative detail". It makes the stroke detail dependent on the zoom level: «*Zoom out big details, zoom in small fine details*». So... **just try zooming in**!

There are other possible options, that you might find more suitable for you. For instance, "Brush detail": «*You can increase and lower topology by simply resizing the brush itself*».

Have a look at the manual for details about all the Adaptive Sculpting options: [link to the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html).

Comment: Maybe mention alternative to relative, like constant for example.. I'm being picky but it's Dyntopo not Dynotopo.

Comment: not picky but completely justified! I fixed it. as for suggesting alternatives: there are plenty of options (I mentioned one) and I just wanted to point in the right direction, for that reason I included a link to the manual